# iMac Speakers very bassy?

Tags: 18.04, apple

I booted up a nice 18.04 live CD to test out whether my hardware was fully working on my iMac. Everything works fine but the speakers just seem very bassy. I investigated and I don't think ubuntu is correctly picking up the 5.1 configuration and is instead using a stereo config perhaps?

I found an article from 2011 by OMG! Ubuntu:

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/07/imac-sound-ubuntu

But I don't have the surround sound option he has.

Is there anyway to get the sound properly working on my iMac. This is the only caveat making me not switch to Ubuntu.